# How can I redirect one blade to another blade without using route file in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes

**How to redirect index.blade to register.blade**

index.blade

```
<a href="{{ url('register') }}">
Click to Channel
</a>
```

register.blade

```
{!!Form::text('name')!!}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example below you have to use route but the url does not change. 
You just change the blade

Use this in index.blade:

```
   <a href="/toregister"><button type="button">Edit/Add Values</button></a>
```

Use this in route file

```
 Route::get('/toregister', 'YourController@redirectToRegister');
```

And this to YourController:

```
public function redirectToRegister() {
   return view('register');
}
```